# Recognize which JS script is performing the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, logging

I don't know if there is a way to recognize which JS script is performing the action which is in progress in a page?! For example, when we click on a button, it's doing something using javascript. But how to know which script and even which line of the script are involved in this event?!

Comment: Check out [VisualEvent](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event). It has been very helpful to me.

Comment: Agreed about VisualEvent.

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of task i can suggest you to use google chrome, its developer tools offer a lot of functonality that most of us dont even use or know. 
just open up your page, then hit F12 to open developer tools. find and click Sources tab, there you will see a tree mapping all the files in your site, then look at the right upper corner of the dev tools, there you will find handlers for your events, and under it a list of event you can look into and pause, next to the pause button its a really useful button "Step over next function call" this will take you through every event related to the JS execution. in this list you will find at the bottom a tab that say "Event Listener Breakpoints" just expand it and you will find every event javascript can check, just look for the events you need, ie. find Mouse, expand it and check click, so in every 'click' the execution stops and you can see whats going on. or just check the whole Mouse event list and it will pause at every mouse event.

Comment: I have been using developer tools so fa. But it's not working as I want. And "Step over next function call" button is disabled.

Comment: you can click over a line number in the sources tab to watch that expression, then reload the page, the execution will pause at the selected line, and  "Step over next function call"  will be enabled.